# Get imageview from Adapter in Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, universal-image-loader

I have Image view list in adapter on click of image I show full screen image. Where I have one button outside of adapter in fragment.

Now I want to get that image in fragment onClick of button to share that image. 
Below code this in adapter where my images are getting download.

I have using Android-Universal-Image-Loader library to show images.

```
@Override
public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
    if(callback != null) {
        Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) img_main_bg.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
        callback.onItemClicked(bitmap);
    }
    spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

How do I get image in fragment?

I already tried interface but onLoadingComplete downloading multiple image at time so I can't get right image on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it following way

first make click listener in that ask for permission to save image

```
imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    imgView = imageView;
                    boolean hasPermission = (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(ImagePagerActivity.this,
                            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
                    if (!hasPermission) {
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(ImagePagerActivity.this,
                                new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                                112);
                    }else
                    {
                        showDialog();
                    }


                }
            });
```

if permission is applied then save image first then share it

```
private void showDialog()
    {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(ImagePagerActivity.this,R.style.MyAlertDialogStyle)
                .setTitle("Select your option")
                .setPositiveButton("Save",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(
                                    DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int which) {
                                imgView.buildDrawingCache();
                                Bitmap bm = imgView
                                        .getDrawingCache();
                                OutputStream fOut = null;
                                try {
                                    File root = new File(
                                            Environment
                                                    .getExternalStorageDirectory()
                                                    + File.separator
                                                    + "Beauty"
                                                    + File.separator);
                                    if (!root.exists())
                                        root.mkdirs();
                                    File sdImageMainDirectory = new File(
                                            root,
                                            System.currentTimeMillis()
                                                    + ".jpg");
                                    fOut = new FileOutputStream(
                                            sdImageMainDirectory);
                                    bm.compress(
                                            Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,
                                            100, fOut);
                                    fOut.flush();
                                    fOut.close();
                                    Toast.makeText(
                                            ImagePagerActivity.this,
                                            "File saved at  Beauty  folder",
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                            .show();
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    Toast.makeText(
                                            ImagePagerActivity.this,
                                            "Error occured. Please try again later.",
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                            .show();
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        })
                .setNegativeButton("Share",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(
                                    DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int which) {
                                try {
                                    imgView.buildDrawingCache();
                                    Bitmap bm = imgView
                                            .getDrawingCache();
                                    OutputStream fOut = null;

                                    File root = new File(
                                            Environment
                                                    .getExternalStorageDirectory()
                                                    + File.separator
                                                    + " Beauty"
                                                    + File.separator);
                                    if (!root.exists())
                                        root.mkdirs();
                                    File sdImageMainDirectory = new File(
                                            root, "1.jpg");
                                    fOut = new FileOutputStream(
                                            sdImageMainDirectory);
                                    bm.compress(
                                            Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,
                                            100, fOut);
                                    fOut.flush();
                                    fOut.close();

                                    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(
                                            Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                                    Uri phototUri = Uri
                                            .fromFile(sdImageMainDirectory);
                                    shareIntent.setData(phototUri);
                                    shareIntent
                                            .setType("image/png");
                                    shareIntent.putExtra(
                                            Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,
                                            phototUri);
                                    startActivityForResult(Intent
                                                    .createChooser(
                                                            shareIntent,
                                                            "share using"),
                                            2);

                                } catch (Exception ce) {
                                    ce.printStackTrace();
                                }

                            }
                        })

                .show();
    }
```